# How can I make a simple left join with null condition run faster?

Tags: mysql, query-performance, aws

I've got two very simple tables

```
CREATE TABLE `track` (
  `id` char(36) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `number` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  `title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '2000-01-01 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `updated` (`updated`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;

CREATE TABLE `trackindex` (
  `track_id` varchar(36) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `track_updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`track_id`),
  KEY `track_updated` (`track_updated`),
  KEY `track_id-track_updated` (`track_id`,`track_updated`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;
```

The `track` table has about 2.1 million rows. The following query takes about 1 minute to complete :

```
SELECT 
    trackindex.track_id AS track_id1_26_0_,
    trackindex.track_updated AS track_up2_26_0_
FROM
    trackindex
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    track ON trackindex.track_id = track.id
WHERE
    track.id IS NULL
        OR trackindex.track_updated <> track.updated
LIMIT 50
```

[image]

What can I do to make this query run faster?

Side note : the query exectures on an AWS RDS `db.m6g.xlarge` instance which can do 1500 IOPS.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following [composite](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) index :

```
alter table track add index `id_updated`(`id`,`updated`);
```

It is known that `OR` it's a performance killer. You could rewrite the query using UNION ALL .

```
SELECT ti.track_id AS track_id1_26_0_,
       ti.track_updated AS track_up2_26_0_
FROM trackindex ti 
LEFT OUTER JOIN track  t ON ti.track_id = t.id
WHERE t.id IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT ti.track_id AS track_id1_26_0_,
       ti.track_updated AS track_up2_26_0_
FROM trackindex ti 
LEFT OUTER JOIN track  t ON ti.track_id = t.id
WHERE ti.track_updated <> t.updated 
LIMIT 50 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query essentially states that you want all rows which *either* have no matching `track` row, *or* have a `track` row which has a different `updated` time.

So you can try the following equivalent query

```
SELECT 
    ti.track_id AS track_id1_26_0_,
    ti.track_updated AS track_up2_26_0_
FROM
    trackindex ti
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM
        track t
    WHERE
        ti.track_id = t.id
        AND ti.track_updated = t.updated
)
LIMIT 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this gives what you want:

```
SELECT  ti.track_id AS track_id1_26_0_,
        ti.track_updated AS track_up2_26_0_
    FROM  trackindex AS ti
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  track  ON ti.track_id = track.id
      AND  ti.track_updated = track.updated
    WHERE  track.id IS NULL
    LIMIT  50
```

It may not be correct if the mapping is not what it expects.  Is it 1:many, or what?

In any case, this is redundant, hence unnecessary:

```
KEY `track_id-track_updated` (`track_id`,`track_updated`)
```

You have no `ORDER BY`, so the `LIMIT` is free to give you *any* 50.  If you add an `ORDER BY`, we would need to analyze things again; the indexing may change.